# Python - how to return to for loop using +=

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have an issue with a for loop I wrote, I can't get the for loop to return to the first for statement:

```
def output(query,page,max_page):
    """
    Parameters:
        query: a string
        max_page: maximum pages to be crawled per day, integer

    Returns:
    List of news dictionaries in a list: [[{...},{...}..],[{...},]]
    """
    news_dicts_all = []
    news_dicts = []
    # best to concatenate urls here
    date_range = get_dates()
    for date in get_dates():
        s_date = date.replace(".","")
        while page < max_page:
            url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&query=" + query + "&sort=0&ds=" + date + "&de=" + date + "&nso=so%3Ar%2Cp%3Afrom" + s_date + "to" + s_date + "%2Ca%3A&start=" + str(page)
            header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
            req = requests.get(url,headers=header)
            cont = req.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, 'html.parser')
            for urls in soup.select("._sp_each_url"):
                try:
                    if urls["href"].startswith("https://news.naver.com"):
                        news_detail = get_news(urls["href"])
                        adict = dict()
                        adict["title"] = news_detail[0]
                        adict["date"] = news_detail[1]
                        adict["company"] = news_detail[3]
                        adict["text"] = news_detail[2]
                        news_dicts.append(adict)
                except Exception as e:
                    continue
            page += 10
        news_dicts_all.append(news_dicts)
    return news_dicts_all
```

I've executed the code, and it seems that `page +=` gets the code back to "`while`" part, but would not get back to `for date in get_dates()` part after the page reaches `max_page`.

What I would want essentially is the code to return to `for date in get_dates()` after it reaches `max_page`, but I don't know how I can make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset `page` so when it moves onto the next date in your for loop, `page > max_page` is already true so it skips the while loop completely.

You'll need to do something like change your `page` argument to `start_page` then have `page = start_page` at the start of your for loop.